# Search and display image by code number ASP.NET/VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hoping that you could help me with this.

I am working with some ASP web forms and behind the scenes I have VB.net coding. What I am trying to achieve is when the user types in a code number in text box it should display the image on form according to the code input.
The code is below, however is not working.

```
 Private Sub retrievepicture()
    Dim code As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim imagepath As String = "\\256.167.564.200\images\"
    Dim file As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(imagepath, code & "*.gif")
    Image1.ImageUrl = "\\256.167.564.200\pics\" & code & "*.gif"
End Sub
```

Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks